# Google Maps api does not use my global variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twig

I'm using TWIG at symfony 2.8 and Google Maps api to create list of pins for map.

I've created script that makes array of all pins, but now I can't get it into the map - Map does not "see" my array. Also when I tried to put my code into InitMap - it doesn't work at all.

Question: How to use my `locations` with Google Map, and also get loop from `Twig`?

<kbd>code</kbd>

```
var locations = [];
{% for event in incoming_events %}
    var event_id = {{ event.id|json_encode|raw }};
    var event_name = {{ event.name|json_encode|raw }};
    var event_lat = {{ event.geoMarker.lat|json_encode|raw }};
    var event_lng = {{ event.geoMarker.lng|json_encode|raw }};
    console.log(event_id);
    console.log(event_name);
    console.log(event_lat);
    console.log(event_lng);
    locations.push.apply(locations, [event_name, event_lat, event_lng, event_id]);
{% endfor %}
console.log( locations );
```

<kbd>Google Maps script</kbd>

```
function initMap() {
    var event_one = {lat: 52.742943, lng: 23.450317};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('tab-mapawydarzen'), {
        zoom: 6,
        center: event_one,
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            icon: '../img/pins/notactive.png',
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                marker.setIcon('../img/pins/active.png');
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you actually verify that the `twig` variable `incoming_events` isnn't empty?

Comment: It's not empty, because in console it gives me full array of data.

Comment: Where/when's the inline JS from the Twig file?  Where/when's the call to initMap?  Most likely you're calling `initMap` before the inline JS gets defined.

Comment: My JS looks like that in file:
'<script>inline twig scripts</script>
<script async defer ="url-to-googlemap.js">'

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easier than I could imagine...

Google script was default "async defer", while my normal script was without these variables. When I've did:

```
<script async defer>My script</script><script async defer src="googlemap.js"></script>
```

It worked fine. Thank you for help.